# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {a\sin bx -b\sin ax}{x^2 \sin ax}$ witouth L'Hopital, what is my mistake?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I was working on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660046/find-this-limit-without-using-lhospitals-rule) question.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {a\sin bx -b\sin ax}{x^2 \sin ax}$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1}{x^2} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac { \frac {1}{abx}}{\frac {1}{abx}} \cdot \dfrac {a\sin bx -b\sin ax}{\sin ax}$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1}{x^2} \cdot \dfrac {\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin bx}{bx}- \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax}}{\frac 1b \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin ax}{ax}}$

$b \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1}{x^2} \cdot \dfrac {b-a}{a}$

It seems like this limit does not exist, but if you apply L'Hopital's rule you seem to get an answer. What is wrong with what I did?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660046/find-this-limit-without-using-lhospitals-rule

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that is the question I was trying to solve

Comment: You cannot write $\lim a_n b_n = \lim a_n \lim b_n$ until you know that the occuring limits exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is that
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin cx}{cx}
= 1$, not $c$,
so your fraction is
$\frac1{x^2}\frac{1-1}{1/b}$
which is still indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ if both the limits exist and are finite. So there is an error in the 2nd line of your proof where you have separated $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin bx}{bx}=1$. So the numerator in your last limit is $1-1=0$, and this means that you wrote your limit as a product "$\frac10\times0"$, from where you cannot get information.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use Taylor expansion. You know what is Taylor series for $sin(x)$. So, develop accordingly the different terms.

For the numerator, you will have $\frac{1}{6} x^3 \left(a^3 b-a b^3\right)+O\left(x^4\right)$ and for the denominator $a x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$. So, the result should be $$\frac{1}{6} \left(a^2 b-b^3\right)$$ you can still simplify to $$\frac{1}{6} b (a-b) (a+b)$$